# handling multiple @PathVariable attributes in a spring controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Is there ant way to modify a method like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{pagina}")
public String pagina(Model model, @PathVariable("pagina") String pagina) {
    return "public/pagina";
}
```

for allow handle an unknwon number of @PathVariable parameter? I want urls like this:

```
/<server>/<app>/<path>/.../<path>
```

be handled this way:

- the last path variable attribute should be stored in a separated variable;
- the other path varaiables should be stored in a ArrayList.

anyone knows if this is possible?

Comment: You'd have to write it yourself with a custom `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`.

Answer (score 1):

Path variables work with specific path variables, in compliance with the URI template spec.  You could add a method argument for HttpServletRequest and get the URL from it and then parse out what you want.

If you look at the docs, you might also consider using a matrix variable in your request mapping.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-requestmapping